# Simple ODE existence

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $F : \mathbb{R}\times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function. Suppose that the initial value problem

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = F(x(t),t) $$
$$x(0) = \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$$

has a solution in $[0,T]$.

Why does is true that there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that the problem

$$ \frac{dx_{\epsilon}}{dt} = F(x_{\epsilon}(t),t) $$
$$x(0) = \alpha + \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$$
has solution in $[0,T]$ for every $\epsilon \in (0,\epsilon_0)?$

I imagine that this is easy, but I was not able to solve it. I tried a pedestrian approach as follows:

Deny the thesis. Then for every $k > 0$ there exists $l_k < \frac{1}{k}$ such that the problem

$$ \frac{dx_{l_k}}{dt} = F(x_{l_k}(t),t) $$
$$x(0) = \alpha + l_k \in \mathbb{R}$$
has no solution in $[0,T]$.
That is, there exists a family of ODE's that cannot be solved in $[0,T].$
But since $l_k \to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ the "limit equation" tend to the original one, that can be solved. And it must be a contradiction. The problem is that I am not able to formalize this argument. How to do so? Or, how can I prove (following other way, possible) to solve this problem?

It came from the proof of Weak Maximum Principle for PDE's.

Comment: Your wording implies that you may be expecting this to be not too involved. If I understand this correctly, this is the proof of an initial value problem's dependence on initial conditions. It's rather involved. I can give it below if that is what you'd like.

Comment: I would like this!

Comment: @MattS I would like it too